# Scraping using flutter and beautiful soup for flutter and dart

Tags: python, flutter, dart, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am trying to scrape a website using beautiful soup for flutter, the problem is that in python you can do this:

```
soup.find('table', {'id':'list_table'})
```

while in dart you only can do this:

```
soup.find_all('table')
```

This is not efficient, how am I supposed to find element with specific attributes. Even the attributes function given by dart is not working as that of python, it only shows the attributes that are in an element and it does not help in searching for elements that has specific attributes. So how to perform the same operations that are present in dart python using dart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `soup.select();` This function expects 1 argument that is the **CSS selector**. You can easily get it using **Chrome dev tools**.